# 'Zeitwerk::SetupRequired' error on rails. What does it mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zeitwerk

I got the error ***"Zeitwerk::SetupRequired: please, finish your configuration and call Zeitwerk::Loader#setup once all is ready"*** while browsing my locally running rails app. (Rails v6.0.6)

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Only part of the app was broken. This cropped up somewhat out of the blue. I'd been messing around with something, but it was on an app which was previously running fine.

I started by googling what Zeitwerk is :-)  So I presumed I have problem with "loading" of some my rails code.

I tried running `rails zeitwerk:check` which gives output like:

```
Sidekiq 7.0
Hold on, I am eager loading the application.

WARNING: The following directories will only be checked if you configure
them to be eager loaded:

  /path/to/my/rails/app/lib
  /path/to/my/rails/app/mailer_previews

You may verify them manually, or add them to config.eager_load_paths
in config/application.rb and run zeitwerk:check again.

Otherwise, all is good!
```

That seems to be fairly normal output (e.g. it [fits with what this guide shows](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/rails/upgrade/zeitwerk/upgrading-to-zeitwerk.html#checking-for-zeitwerk-compatibility-issues))

Answer (score 0):

Restart the rails app server to fix it!

I'd had a pretty good run of not bothering to restart my local app server, so it took me way too long to think of doing this, but obviously if rails has got its knickers in a twist with anything related to "loading" of code (which is what Zeitwerk is all about) then that should be a first thing to try.